# Delete a row based on a word in a cell of a certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following macro to delete a row if the content of a cell is the **exact word** "Single Word", but i actually want to delete the row if the content of the cell **contain the word** "single" regardless the rest of the words in the same cell and regardleds lower or uppercase.
Any ideas how can i achieve that ?

```
Dim ws251120 As Worksheet
Dim i251120 As Long
For Each ws251120 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i251120 = 400 To 1 Step -1
        If ws251120.Cells(i251120, "A").Value = "Single Word" Then
            ws251120.Rows(i251120).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: `like` and `*` (wildcards) would be a good place to start.  Or the 'search' excel formula

Comment: The above suggestion meant to replace `...).Value = "Single Word" ` with `...).Value like "*single*"`